# Specify subtitle framerate?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to hardcode subtitles into a movie. I'm using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mkv -vf subtitles=a.sub a.mp4
```

The problem is, the subtitles are out of sync and only work if I manually define subtitle FPS to 25 in smplayer. Is there a way I could also specify that for ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

try this command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles=input.srt,fps=25 withsub.mp4
```

I specified fps in command `fps=25` now edit your command as per requirement.

Comment: This does not seem to have any impact on the output